# How can I set an initial value for ListWheelScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: this]

I made time picker in my app like the above. Each number is a different `ListWheelScrollView` and I would like to set an initial value for them. How can I do this?

```dart
List<Widget> createNumbers(context, maxNum) {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= maxNum; i++) {
    widgets.add(
      Text(
        i.toString(), 
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      ),
    );
  }
  return widgets;
}

double itemExtent = 20;

//^^These parts are for decoration and generating the numbers)^^

int initialNumber = 11; // I want this to be the initial number

return ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: itemExtent,
  physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
  children: createNumbers(context, 59),
);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't set default value for ListWheelScrollView, but what if you jump to that value after build:

```
  initListData(_) async {
    _controller.jumpToItem(/* index of your default value */);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(initListData);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FixedExtentScrollController()` along with `FixedExtentScrollPhysics()`

```dart
ListWheelScrollView(
  physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
  controller: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem:_yourInitialItemIndex),
),
```